# How to do a PCA with netcdf data in R

Tags: r, pca, netcdf

I have the following netcdf file in R:

```
"file oceandata.nc has 2 dimensions:"
"lon   Size: 2160"
"lat   Size: 900"
"------------------------"
"file oceandata.nc has 14 variables:"
"float bio1[lon,lat]  Longname:bio1: Annual Mean Temp Missval:1e+30"
"float bio4[lon,lat]  Longname:bio4: Temp Seasonality (standard deviation * 100) Missval:1e+30"
"float bio8[lon,lat]  Longname:bio8: Mean Temp of Wettest Quarter Missval:1e+30"
"float bio9[lon,lat]  Longname:bio9: Mean Temp of Driest Quarter Missval:1e+30"
"float bio10[lon,lat]  Longname:bio10: Mean Temp of Warmest Quarter Missval:1e+30"
"float bio11[lon,lat]  Longname:bio11: Mean Temp of Coldest Quarter Missval:1e+30"
"float bio12[lon,lat]  Longname:bio12: Annual Precipitation Missval:1e+30"
"float bio13[lon,lat]  Longname:bio13: Precipitation of Wettest Month Missval:1e+30"
"float bio14[lon,lat]  Longname:bio14: Precipitation of Driest Month Missval:1e+30"
"float bio15[lon,lat]  Longname:bio15: Precipitation Seasonality (coefficient of variation) Missval:1e+30"
"float bio16[lon,lat]  Longname:bio16: Precipitation of Wettest Quarter Missval:1e+30"
"float bio17[lon,lat]  Longname:bio17: Precipitation of Driest Quarter Missval:1e+30"
"float bio18[lon,lat]  Longname:bio18: Precipitation of Warmest Quarter Missval:1e+30"
"float bio19[lon,lat]  Longname:bio19: Precipitation of Coldest Quarter Missval:1e+30"
```

I would like to perform a PCA on the 14 variables in the file but am unsure as to how to go about this or if the data needs to be converted to a different format before I can do this.

So far I have done (error message below):

```
ocean <- open.ncdf("oceandata.nc")

bio1 <- get.var.ncdf(nc=ncdf, varid="bio1")

bio4 <- get.var.ncdf(nc=ncdf, varid="bio4")

bio8 <- get.var.ncdf(nc=ncdf, varid="bio8")

bio9 <- get.var.ncdf(nc=ncdf, varid="bio9")

dim(bio1)
```

[1] 2160  900

```
class(bio1)
```

[1] "matrix"

```
oceanvars <- cbind(bio1,bio4, bio8, bio9)

colnames(oceanvars) <- c("bio1", "bio4", "bio8", "bio9")
```

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("bio1", "bio4", "bio8", "bio9" : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

```
pairs(oceanvars)
```

Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

```
pca1 <- princomp(oceanvars, scores=TRUE, cor=TRUE)
```

Error in princomp.default(oceanvars, scores = TRUE, cor = TRUE) : 'princomp' can only be used with more units than variables

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you assuming that `cbind`ing 4 matrices with 900 columns each, results in a matrix object with 4 columns, allowing to assign c("bio1", "bio4", "bio8", "bio9") as column names.

So as far as I understand you have for the four variables `Annual Mean Temp`, `Temp Seasonality`, `Mean Temp of Wettest Quarter` and `Mean Temp of Driest Quarter` in total 1944000 spatial objects which you want to analyze by a PCA.

Unfortunately you do not provide a reproducible example, but creating `oceanvars` by

```
oceanvars <- cbind( c(bio1), c(bio4), c(bio8), c(bio9) )
```

should already do the trick. The reason is, that `c()` melts a matrix to a simple vector.

A more general and clean procedure would involve to `melt` your matrices to 3-column `data.frames` or at this size even better `data.tables` and then `merge` them by the combination of `lon`and `lat` and then just provide the value columns as matrix to `princomp`.